# Makevars for C functions in package

Tags: r, c

I need help in writing a `Makevars` file
for a package including C functions which them will be calles using .C(...)

The directory contains

```
Makevars (empty at the moment)
midicsvR-package.c (automatically generated)
c_csvmidi.c (contains one of the C functions to be called with .C())
c_midicsv.c (contains another one of the C functions to be called with .C())

midio.c            
csv.c

midio.h
csv.h              
midifile.h         
types.h
version.h
```

I can compile the so files which then are called with .C() like this

`R CMD SHLIB -o c_midicsv.so c_midicsv.c midio.c csv.c`

`R CMD SHLIB -o c_csvmidi.so c_csvmidi.c midio.c csv.c`

These functions work when called with .C() in R functions.
What do I need to write into `Makevars` so this happens automatically at
package installation.

My problem is that `midio.c` and `csv.c` contain support functions for `c_midicsv.c` and `c_csvmidi.c`, so no `so` is needed for the files.

Can anybody give me a link to a good tutorial how to create c files which after compilation and linking can be used via `.Call(...)` in R?

I am willing to learn, but have not found an introduction which helps me getting thus up and running.

Answer (score 5):

You most likely do not need anything extra. *If nothing special is needed* R will automatically compile all files with proper names denoting C or C++ code (and even Fortran code but mixing Fortran and C/C++ is trickier).  It will then create the dynamic library and ensure the package loads it. Look at existing CRAN packages, for example

- `MASS` by Venables and Ripley just has two source files and no `Makevars`:     https://github.com/cran/MASS/tree/master/src ;
- `nnet` by Ripley has only one source file and no `Makevars`:
  https://github.com/cran/nnet/tree/master/src ;
- `rpart` by Therneau, Atkinson and Ripley has a bunch of files but no `Makevars`:   https://github.com/cran/rpart/tree/master/src

There are some extra concerns about the `NAMESPACE` file and the possible registrations but that was not part of your question.  But I think you are done as far as `src/Makevars` is concerned.

Lastly, consider using `.Call()`.  Using `.C()` is discouraged as discussed fairly extensively in the last few years (check for example the mailing archive for r-package-devel).

*Edit:* For kicks, I just tried to set up a *minimal* example starting from R's own `package.skeleton()`.  It is not *that* hard, and all the relevant information has long been in *Writing R Extension*.  Plus, there are over 20k packages on CRAN which over 4k contain compiled code. These all provide working examples. I am sure you can pick a suitable minimal one, either plain C or using C++ via one of the helper packages interfacing C++.